# Rewrite Lebesgue integral over a centered interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Given a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, define the integral over an interval centered at $x$: $$f_c(x)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-c}^{x+c} f(t)\,dt$$

There is a stated result that we can rewrite $f_c(x)$ into $$f_c(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-t)\frac{1}{2c}\mathbf{1}_{[-c,c]}\,dt$$where $\mathbb{1}_{[-c,c]}$ is the indicator function of $[-c,c]$.

But it seems to be counter-intuitive and I don't know how to proceed. Any idea how to show this is true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
f_c(x) &=& \int {1 \over 2c} 1_{[x-c,x+c]}(t) f(t) dt \\
&=& \int {1 \over 2c} 1_{[-c,+c]}(t-x) f(t) dt \\
&=& \int {1 \over 2c} 1_{[-c,+c]}(x-t) f(t) dt \\
&=& \int {1 \over 2c} 1_{[-c,+c]}(\tau) f(x-\tau) dt \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why is it necessary for the third equality? Can't we just go with the second equality? Something is missing in my mind..

Comment: I don't understand your question, the last line is what you are trying to show.

Comment: Sorry, I figured this out. Yes, that's what I was trying to show, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of the indicator function,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) \frac{1}{2c} 1_{[-c,c]} \,dt = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{-c}^{c} f(x-t) \,dt.
$$
Now just make a change of variables $s=x-t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after change of variable $s=x-t$, then $dt$ becomes $d(x-s)$, which gives us a negative sign. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It also changes the limits of integration to be backwards, so there are two minus signs that cancel out